# About Example 1.8.2 in Durrett: Probability Theory and Examples

Tags: probability-theory

The example is about tail $\sigma$-field. Given i.i.d. r.v. $ X_1, X_2, \dots $ and the partial sum $ S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n $. The example says that

$\{ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n > 0 \} \notin \mathcal{T}$ and

$\{ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n/c_n > x \} \in \mathcal{T}$ if $c_n \rightarrow \infty$,

where $\mathcal{T} = \cap_n \mathcal{F}'_n = \cap_n \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$ is the tail $\sigma$-field.

I am always getting in trouble with the $\limsup$ stuff. Can anyone provide some explainations about the above example. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: OK. What do you fail to understand specifically, say about the second case?

Comment: @Did Thanks for your response. I was thinking in the following way. First, $ \{\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n > 0\} $ is the event $\{ \inf_n \sup_{m\geq n} S_m > 0\}$. Since $\inf$ of all $\sup_{m\geq n} S_m > 0 $, we have $\cap_n \{\sup_{m\geq n} S_m > 0\}$ and hence the set is equivalent to $\cap_n \cup_{m\geq n} \{S_m > 0\}$. Since $S_m = X_1 + \dots + X_m $ is not measurable with respect to all $\sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, \dots)$ for all $n$, the set $\{S_m > 0\} \notin \mathcal{T}$ and hence $ \{\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n > 0\} \notin \mathcal{T}$.

Comment: @Did However, when going throught the similar reasoning in the second case, it seems still not in $\mathcal{T}$. I don't know which step goes wrong. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durrett mentions that, intuitively, an event is in the tail sigma algebra when it is not influenced by changing the value of a finite number of the $X_n$. Let me handwave just for a bit. Suppose that in the first one the $\limsup$ is positive and finite. Then you could change the value of $X_1$ to a very large negative number, so as to make the $\limsup$ of the sum negative. However, in the second example, any finite number of additions to the values of the $X$ variables will leave the event unchanged, because the large $c_n$ in the denominator will get rid of them eventually.

This may help you: note that, for any fixed value of $k$,

> $\limsup {X_1+\dots+X_n\over c_n}>x$ if and only if the shifted $\limsup{X_{k+1}+\dots+X_{k+n}\over c_{k+n}}>x$.

Why is that? Suppose that the first $\limsup$ equals $\alpha$. Then you can find arbitrarily large $n_j>>k$ such that 
$${X_1+\dots+X_{n_j}\over c_{n_j}}\to \alpha$$ 
as $j\to\infty.$ Then it only suffices to write
$${X_{1}+\dots+X_{k}\over c_{k+{n_j}}}+{X_{k+1}+\dots+X_{k+{n_j}}\over c_{k+{n_j}}}\to\alpha$$ as $j\to\infty$ to assert the answer, because the first fraction approaches zero. Again: a finite number of values don't affect the result.

Now, the terms of the original $\limsup$ are not in $\mathcal F'_m$ for $m>k$, but the terms of the $\limsup$ shifted by $k$ will belong to $\mathcal F'_k$ for any $k$. This should be enough to assert the measurability with respect to $\mathcal T$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For every $k$, 
$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\,S_n/c_n=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\,(S_{k+n}-S_k)/c_{k+n}.
$$
This identity uses the fact that $c_n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help.